# Importing Armadillo C++ library into Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, armadillo

I'm a mac user and am trying to install and import C++ Armadillo library. Here are the steps I've had so far:

1) I downloaded the Armadillo library from its website.

2) I went over the Readme.txt file in the download file explaining how to install it.

3) I used CMake to make the armadillo download files into binary files.

4) Then by using terminal and the code sudo make install, I installed the binary codes and they generated some "library-like" files: libarmadillo.4.0.2.dylib, libarmadillo.4.dylib, lib armadillo.dylib

5) I then copied all these files into /url/lib directory.

6) Now I have my Xcode program running and I'm trying to include the armadillo library via the include command. The problem is Xcode highlights this line and it says "armadillo file not found". Could anyone please help me solve this issue?

Thanks very much,

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17056335/1080929

Comment: @Sepehr, did you ever solve your issues? I'm having the same problems!

Comment: Hi @WillAndrew, unfortunately, I was not able to solve it. I primarily wanted to program with Rcpp and for some reasons I can compile armadillo codes in R studion after including the RcppArmadillo package. I suggest trying Martin's solution below, it might help. Please let me know if it helps. I was not actually able to solve it with his solution either :(

Comment: @Sepehr, I accidentally solved my problem by removing libarmadillo.dylib from the "Link Binary with Libraries" section, program now compiles properly (although I have no idea why!)

Comment: @WillAndrew, glad that you were able to solve it. These "logistics" sometimes become very tedious. Now that you've solved it, the fun part begins :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the following things in your build settings:

- Header Search Paths: /path/to/armadillo/include (e.g. something like /url/lib/armadillo/include)

This is all you need for your source to compile. However, in order to get your program to link, you will also need the following:

- Library Search Paths: /path/to/armadillo/libraries (e.g. something like /url/lib/armadillo/lib)
- Other Linker Flags: -larmadillo (or: add the armadillo library to your Link build phase using the GUI)

If you're not exactly sure how to properly build and install armadillo (e.g. which prefix to use when configuring), I highly recommend using a package manager such as **MacPorts** to do it for you,

1. Install port from [here](http://www.macports.org/install.php)
2. run the following command:

> sudo port install armadillo
>
> Your header path and library path will be: /opt/local/include and /opt/local/lib respectively