# How to use openCV and Armadillo C++ Libs in iOS (Xcode)?

Tags: ios, xcode, armadillo

Please tell me if anybody knows how to link openCV and Armadillo C++ library into my iOS project?

Comment: [How to link OpenCV Framework](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/hello/hello.html)

Comment: [How to link Armadillo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136776/linking-armadillo-with-xcode)

Comment: @NSNoob Thanks for your support. Hope it will help to solve my problem.